# Where is the template file for the front-end grid view in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, template, grid

I need to overwrite the front-end grid view but cannot find the correct file. This is the grid view that appears as a front end option for categories and search - not the admin grid.

Answer (score 0):

The grid view is included in the following file with the product list:

`/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current file of the front-end grid view by **Enabling** the **Magento Path hint** from the configurations.

Check this Magento doc for more info: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/template-path-hints.html